What are these root-like structures growing in the upper part of a tree?
In the UK, I saw these root-like structures growing from the upper parts of a tree. I thought they might be parasitic but they're part of the tree itself, and join to the trunk as branches.
What are they?


Do you know what type of tree it is and do you have any better lit photos, it might help to get a full answer.

Likely a duplicate of: https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/77434/16866

In the absence of better photos and a species ID on the tree there are a few options:

Adventitious roots. These are roots produced from parts of the plant apart from the main root system. They are very common in some plants, and some species of trees are well known for doing this. I think Willows, particularly White Willows (Salix alba) will do this naturally when a branch touches the ground, but other species can too. Adventitious roots can also form inside hollows inside the plant where rotting material/soil accumulates.

Witches' broom. This is where a woody plant an abnormal growth, often caused by an infection. I guess you could liken it to a cancer in animals - it's essentially a diseased part of the plant. These typically present as a bundle of quite twisted and dense branches growing from an unusual place on a branch - I think it this is the most likely option here.

A sport. These are also abnormal growths on a plant, but they aren't caused by infection, they are genetic mutations, which result in an abnormal form. If you have a variegated plant (one with multi-coloured leaves, usually streaks of white/cream on green) at home and it produces totally green stems - that's a sport (though often a reversion of a sport in this case as variegation is often produced by sports in the first place and then propagated for the difference), or you might have even seen a normally green plant produce variegation itself. Some sports result in differences in growth habit such as branching patterns.

These aren't roots at all, merely a branch that has fallen and gotten caught. Roots tend to have different textured bark to branches and be less straight, so it is often easy to identify, but I can't tell from this photo.



Very hard to tell from the photo due to the lighting.  Some trees, like the Banyan (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banyan) grow roots from their branches that run down to the ground and allow the tree to spread out horizontally.
